# MySQL FullText search without FULLTEXT index

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search, indexing

Within one of our systems we have an option that switches the search system between a `LIKE` search, or a FullText search with either `IN BOOLEAN MODE` or `WITH QUERY EXPANSION`
For some reason, the FULLTEXT index was missing but when the system was set to be `IN BOOLEAN MODE` the query still worked, in the case of `WITH QUERY EXPANSION` the query failed with:

> 1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

I'm a little confused here as these are both FULLTEXT searches but one seems to work without the Index even existing!.

Am i missing something?

FYI this is using MySQL 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argh, just found the answer in the MySQL docs.

With regard to searches `IN BOOLEAN MODE`..

> They can work even without a FULLTEXT 
>   index, although a search executed in
>   this fashion would be quite slow.